# keeping (filtering) observations in df1 based on a variable from another dataset (df2)

Tags: python, join, merge, filtering

I have a large dataset (df1) with multiple observations per user (6 million rows), I want to only see observations from certain users. The selected list of users comes from another dataset (df2) (4000 users).
df1 contains all content of df2.
here is the simplisized sample:

```
df1:
   date_stata  hour user  
0  20mar2023     9  a              
1  20mar2023     9  a              
2  20mar2023     9  a              
3  20mar2023     9  b             
4  20mar2023     9  b
5  20mar2023    12  c
```

```
df2:
   date_stata  hour user  
0    a              
1    c
```

How should I do it in Python os Stata?

I want my output to be like below:

```
  date_stata  hour user  
0  20mar2023     9  a              
1  20mar2023     9  a              
2  20mar2023     9  a                           
3  20mar2023    12  c
```

I've tried this:

```
# Filter the DataFrame based on matching values in the "user" column
filtered_df = df.merge(df2[['user']], on='user', how='inner')
```

and gave me wrong results

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to give a complete answer in code without a proper sample of the data but in general.

1. Create a logical mask that is True only where the users in df2 appear in df1:

   `logical_mask = df1['user'].isin(df2['user'])`
2. filter df1 using the mask:

   `df_res = df1[logical_mask]`

Comment: Thank you for helping. 
I provided the sample in my question.

I tried your code but the result is 
#     user
0     2
1     3

So it's basically giving me the df2
While I want the filtered df1 based on content of user column in df2.

Comment: are you sure that in the second line you used df1 and not df2?